AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'ucry'. Did you mean: 'cry'?
I am trying to update my code to latest version of qiskit==1.1.1 Earlier we used to have a gate called as qc.ucry, but now I am getting an error as below:
AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'ucry'. Did you mean: 'cry'?

Please help me in resolving this Error?
Edit1
Earlier my below syntax used to work.
qc.ucry(theta_j.tolist(), qc.qubits[j+1:], qc.qubits[j])

Now, I have changed it to as below:
qc.append(UCRYGate(theta_j.tolist(), qc.qubits[j+1:] + qc.qubits[j] ))

But this syntax is giving me an Error as below:
    qc.append(UCRYGate(theta_j.tolist(), qc.qubits[j+1:] + qc.qubits[j] ))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Qubit") to list


The methods ucrx(), ucry(), and ucrz() have been removed from QuantumCircuit since version 1.0
Now, to add a uniformly-controlled Pauli-Y rotation to your circuit, you have to do it as follows:
from qiskit.circuit.library import UCRYGate

angles = [np.pi / 4, np.pi / 2, 3 * np.pi / 4, np.pi]
controls = [0, 1]
target = [2]

circ.append(UCRYGate(angles), controls + target)


Thank you for the response @Egretta.Thula for the response.  Now I am getting an Error  TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Qubit") to list. Please suggest some correction?

QuantumCircuit.append takes a list of qubits. I splitted the list into two parts - controls and target - for clarification. The target should be a list also even if it contains one qubit only, otherwise you will not be able to concatenate the controls and target in one list.

Thank you @Egretta.Thula for great help.
